# AngularJs orderBy a deep field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, My question has 2 parts, but first, here is the sample data I am working on:

```
    var candidates = [{
        "candidateId": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "email": "Smith@example.com",
        "tasks": [{"taskId":1, "taskState": 3},
                  {"taskId":2, "taskState": 3},
                  {"taskId":3, "taskState": 3},
                  {"taskId":4, "taskState": 1},
                  {"taskId":5, "taskState": 2}]
        },
        {
        "candidateId": 2,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "Doe@example.com",
        "tasks": [{"taskId":1, "taskState": 3},
                  {"taskId":2, "taskState": 3},
                  {"taskId":3, "taskState": 2},
                  {"taskId":4, "taskState": 3},
                  {"taskId":5, "taskState": 3}]
        }];
```

**First part is:** I want to sort/orderBy the highest number completed tasks number, (say, 3 means completed). been trying all day long to find a solution with no luck. (Tried augmenting the objects by adding a `numOfCompletedTasks` property before attaching them to the scope/vm among other attempts)

**the second part of the question is:** I started to wonder if this is even a task for the front-end, I mean, what if i had a 1000 record, that i have to loop through, and get the number of completed tasks, isn't this a back-end task (what is the best practice here)

Comment: You should sort data in the backend that's the best practice in my opinion. Also, you never know what kind of client your app might be open. Better to make processings on backend

Comment: Creating a custom filter that sorts your array should do it

Answer (score 1):

For the first part you're looking something like this?

```
$scope.candidates = [
    {
      "candidateId": 1,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "email": "Smith@example.com",
      "tasks": [{"taskId":1, "taskState": 3},
                {"taskId":2, "taskState": 3},
                {"taskId":3, "taskState": 3},
                {"taskId":4, "taskState": 1},
                {"taskId":5, "taskState": 2}]
    },
    {
      "candidateId": 2,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "Doe@example.com",
      "tasks": [{"taskId":1, "taskState": 3},
                {"taskId":2, "taskState": 3},
                {"taskId":3, "taskState": 2},
                {"taskId":4, "taskState": 3},
                {"taskId":5, "taskState": 3}]
}];


function customSort(items, field ,value){
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) { 
      item.tasks.sort(function(a, b){
        return (a[value] < b[value] ? 1 : -1);
      }); 
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    var foo = {"taskState": 3};
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return ($filter('filter')(a["tasks"], foo, "strict").length < $filter('filter')(b["tasks"], foo, "strict").length ? 1 : -1);
    });
    return filtered;
}

$scope.candidates = customSort($scope.candidates, "taskState");
```

2nd:
But I still believe it would be wiser to do it on the the back-end.